# Regex negative lookahead issues

Tags: regex

I'm trying to filter our a specific trapbased on message and having some issues. I need to only drop messages that contain the string 'the trap is received from' but do not contain 'mxalFaultCode' (in this order).

Currently, I am using the following:

```
.*(Attention|Warning|Critical)\s+[^\(]+\s+\([^\)]+\):\s+The\s+trap\s+is\s+received\s+from.*(?!mxalFaultCode)
```

This matches the text:

```
_blaa_The trap is received from_blaa_mxalFaultCode_blaa_
```

However, replacing the `?!` with a `?=` also matches, surely the `?!` should fail?

Comment: Try `^.*(Attention|Warning|Critical)\s+[^\(]+\s+\([^)]+\):\s+The\s+trap\s+is\s+received\s+from(?!.*mxalFaultCode).*`

Comment: Edit: I take it back, looks like I miscopied! Thanks

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/gjkNHj/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the negative look ahead *before* the `.*`:

ie change:

```
...from.*(?!mxalFaultCode)
```

to (plus adding a term for spaces):

```
...from\s*(?!mxalFaultCode).*
```

The problem with your attempt is that `.*` will consume `"mxalFaultCode"` *before* the look ahead is applied.

You may also be able to simplify your regex by using a longer look ahead. For example if just requiring `"The trap"` was enough, you could code:

```
...The trap(?!.*mxalFaultCode).*
```

which means `"mxalFaultCode"` may not occur *anywhere* after `"The trap"` (whereas `(?!mxalFaultCode)` means `"mxalFaultCode"` may occur *immediately* after).